# How to add attributes to xml nodes in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

If i wanted to add an attribute to the root element record, can i do this from the sql side?

```
SELECT top 1 'text' as nodeA
                from test as z
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, root('record')
```

i would like to produce the xml like this:

```
 <Root attribute="value">
     <z>
         <NodeA>text</NodeA>
     </z>
 </Root>
```

Comment: Can you show what your table looks like, and what you want your XML to look like??

Comment: @mar_s hi marc, i added an update

Comment: Updated my response to satisfy your requirement ....

Comment: @marc_s woops, i forgot to mark as answer, thanks marc!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the new `FOR XML PATH` syntax:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
   'someValue' AS '@Attribute',
   'text' as 'z/NodeA'
FROM dbo.Test
WHERE....
FOR XML PATH('YourElement'), ROOT('Root')
```

This would give something like

```
<Root>
   <YourElement Attribute="someValue">
      <z>
         <NodeA>text</NodeA>
      </z>
   </YourElement>
</Root>
```

Read more about it here:

- [Simple Example of Creating XML File Using T-SQL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/12/sql-server-simple-example-of-creating-xml-file-using-t-sql)
- [Using XML Serialization with SQL's FOR XML PATH](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlForXmlSerialization.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not doing what is requested.

request:

```
<Root attribute="someValue">
   <YourElement>
      <z>
         <NodeA>text</NodeA>
      </z>
   </YourElement>
</Root>
```

your answer:

```
<Root>
   <YourElement Attribute="someValue">
      <z>
         <NodeA>text</NodeA>
      </z>
   </YourElement>
</Root>
```

I'm doing something similar and using PowerShell to scrub the file before saving it:

scrub reason 1: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements

scrub reason 2: THIS

Comment: It seems that you forgot the link for *scrub reason 2*.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      'someValue' AS '@Attribute',
      (SELECT TOP 1 
              'text' as 'z/NodeA'
               FROM dbo.Test
               WHERE....
               FOR XML PATH('YourElement')
       ) 
FOR XML PATH('ROOT');
```

It should create a xml with ROOT containg attribute and list of ... inside.